# how to check both training/eval performances in tensorflow object_detection

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

When I check the tensorboard for observing the training performance, there only shows the eval_0 (in blue) result.

[image]

While it should be a separate train (in orange) and eval (in blue) result as shown in the website of tensorboard (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard?).

> However, I want to compare the model performance on training dataset
>   and eval dataset.

So I checked the models/research/object_detection/model_main.py and want to know

> if I I can get the precision based on the train and eval dataset by
>   set the flag of **model_dir** to **model/eval** folder and set the
>   flag of **eval_training_data** to **model/train** folder?

```
flags.DEFINE_string('model_dir', None, 'Path to output model directory '
                     'where event and checkpoint files will be written.')

flags.DEFINE_boolean('eval_training_data', False,
                     'If training data should be evaluated for this job. Note '
                     'that one call only use this in eval-only mode, and '
                     '`checkpoint_dir` must be supplied.')
```

And I'm confused with this sentence.

**Note that one call only use this in eval-only mode, and checkpoint_dir must be supplied.**

> Does it means if I just want run it in eval-only mode, then I must set
>   the checkpoint_dir? And if I want to run it with train and eval at the
>   same time, I don't need to set the checkpoint_dir?

Comment: Nice quetion, no answers...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to evaluate your model on validation data you should use:

```
python models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/path/to/pipeline_file --model_dir=/path/to/output_results --checkpoint_dir=/path/to/directory_holding_checkpoint --run_once=True
```

If you want to evaluate your model on training data, you should set 'eval_training_data' as True, that is:

```
python models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/path/to/pipeline_file --model_dir=/path/to/output_results --eval_training_data=True --checkpoint_dir=/path/to/directory_holding_checkpoint --run_once=True
```

---

I also add comments to clarify some of previous options:

**--pipeline_config_path:** path to "pipeline.config" file used to train detection model. This file should include paths to the TFRecords files (train and test files) that you want to evaluate, i.e. :

```
    ...
    train_input_reader: {
        tf_record_input_reader {
                #path to the training TFRecord
                input_path: "/path/to/train.record"
        }
        #path to the label map 
        label_map_path: "/path/to/label_map.pbtxt"
    }
    ...
    eval_input_reader: {
        tf_record_input_reader {
            #path to the testing TFRecord
            input_path: "/path/to/test.record"
        }
        #path to the label map 
        label_map_path: "/path/to/label_map.pbtxt"
    }
    ...
```

**--model_dir**: Output directory where resulting metrics will be written, particularly "events.*" files that can be read by tensorboard.

**--checkpoint_dir**: Directory holding a checkpoint. That is the model directory where checkpoint files ("model.ckpt.*") has been written, either during training process, or after export it by using "export_inference_graph.py".

**--run_once**: True to run just one round of evaluation.