# How to calculate evaluation metrics on training data in TensorFlow's Object Detection API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am using the object detector api for quite a while now so training models and use them for inference is all good. Unfortunately, when using TensorBoard to visualize metrics (such as mAP, AR, classification/localization loss) we only get to see those metrics on the validation set. I'd like to calculate the aforementioned metrics also during training so that we can compare train/validation metrics on Tensorboard.

edit: I've stumbled on this post which addresses the same concern [how to check both training/eval performances in tensorflow object_detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663384/how-to-check-both-training-eval-performances-in-tensorflow-object-detection/54267328?noredirect=1#comment95357856_54267328)

Anyone got a pointer on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate your model on the training data by adding the arguments `--eval_training_data=True --sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=10` to the arguments of `model_main`.
By doing so, you instruct it to perform the evaluation on the training data, and you choose how much to dilute the training data sent to evaluation, since usually the amount of training data is very large. 
The thing is that I don't think it's currently possible to evaluate both on training on validation data, but I don't think it's too bad, since usually evaluation on training data is only for sanity check, and not for actual continuous evaluation the model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! About the flag eval_on_training_data it is stated that it is only used in eval-only mode and a chackpoint_dir must be provided. Is the chackpoint_dir the same as the model_dir? Also, would evaluation on training data not give clues about an overfitted object detector?

Comment: `checkpoint_dir` is the directory in which you have the checkpoint, and `model_dir` is the directory in which you wish to write outputs. It you had a training session, the its `model_dir` would be `checkpoint_dir` to the evaluation session, since that's where the checkpoints are. You can leave the `model_dir` as the same if you wish. Evaluation on training data alone does not tell you if you're overfitted, only if you also evaluate on a different set, i.e. validation set, since overfitting means you're doing a very good job on training data while generalizing poorly to other examples.