# TensorFlow Object Detection mAP - calculated on training or validation dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

During object detection training (using model_main.py), the Mean Average Precision(mAP) values are calculated and saved under tags with the prefix "DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP". These metric values are visible in the [TensorBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVGme.png). Are those metrics evaluated upon the training dataset or the validation dataset?

Comment: What's your context?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Pardon?

Comment: Maybe this [how to check both training/eval performances in tensorflow object_detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663384/how-to-check-both-training-eval-performances-in-tensorflow-object-detection) can help.